# How do I build a BOOT disk!

Tags: boot, disk

I've used Ubuntu a few years ago and got a error regarding a Password. I never had a password for this computer, but it really said I did and I tried and tried to get it corrected.... I finally gave up
I bought the last 64 bit cd-- and when I pulled it out, it had a sractch on it... I don't want to buy another.

I've downloaded the iso file!    I unzipped it and burned it to a DVD  but I can't get it to boot the computer???

what am I doing wrong?
This is the third time I've burned it!  I need help
aj

Comment: I have to ask.  Did you set the boot order in the BIOS to boot from CD/DVD?

Comment: absolutely!  yes I did....

Comment: How did you burn the DVD, and under what OS?

Comment: Using Vista 32 Bit!  and the windows burner software

Comment: I've even tried to UPdate the 11.1 ver to 12 ONLINE and it didn't work!  Got an error message.

Comment: Try burning the ISO to DVD using [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can, under Windows, create a bootable USB Pendrive (I always use this software, and never gave me any issues: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Then, plug it in, on the BIOS, set it to boot from USB, and done, boot up a LiveUSB session, and install from there.